# Images accessed through browser using CloudFront + S3 could not be accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have configured cloud front and distribution name is xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net.
Also distribution is configured as "Use All Edge Locations (Best Performance)" with Cors Configuration.
Cors Configuration is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Now, when we are accessing images from browsers it giving error as below in case for Google Chrome,

"Image from origin 'http://xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.xxxxx.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Can you please tell us why this is creating problem with Google Chrome while it is working well with Other Browsers.

Regards,
ARvind

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure CloudFront to forward Origin header as specified here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-cors